# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "haml":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I got following error after "bundle install"

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "haml":
  In Gemfile:
    haml-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      haml (< 5.0, >= 4.0.6) ruby

    haml (= 4.0.3) ruby
```

In the Gemfile:

```
  gem "haml-rails", :git => "git://github.com/indirect/haml-rails.git"
```

how could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Gemfile` contains something like:

```
gem 'haml', '4.0.3'
```

change it to:

```
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.3'
```

and run `bundle install`.

Comment: Read [this](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) section about `Gemfile`. It explain that does it mean.